# Solve the partial differential equation in two variables.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the partial differential equation
                                         $$u_{yy}-2u_y+u=e^x.$$  
My effort: Auxiliary equation corresponding to this equation is
$$D'^2-2D'+1=0\implies D'=1, 1$$ Therefore, the complementary function is given by
$$Ae^y+Bye^y,$$ where A and B are constants.
Particular integral (P.I) is
$$P.I.=\frac{1}{D'^2-2D'+1}(e^x)=(1-D')^2e^x$$ $$=(1+2D'+3D'^2+\cdots)(e^x)$$ $$=e^x.$$
The solution is $$Ae^y+Bye^y+e^x.$$
Is my solution correct?

Comment: I think there's a typo: in your final answer the second term should be $Bye^y$, correct?

Comment: Yes. You are right. I have fixed the typo.

Comment: @Stephen Donovan is the solution correct now? I am confused since the general solution of PDE is generally in terms of arbitrary functions which is not the case here.

Comment: Although it is weird, I think it is correct: I've worked through it with separation of variables just to be safe and I don't see any other non-trivial homogeneous solutions, so I believe this works. I'm still working on it though, so I'll let you know in a second.

Comment: I can't necessarily prove that that's correct, but I can't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is almost correct, if you replace $A$ and $B$ by two arbitrary functions of $x$.

1. Using a transformation $u\to v e^{x}$, you will get $v_{yy}-2v_y+v=1$;
2. The general solution of $v_{yy}-2v_y+v=1$ is $e^y c_1(x)+e^y y c_2(x)+1$;
3. The full solution is then $u=e^{x}[ c_1(x) e^y+c_2(x) e^y y +1]$.